# Batch File Processing - set line output as wait condition

Tags: batch-file, parallel-processing, command, command-line-arguments

Hi I'm trying to write a windows command script that executes two commands.  The first never fully finishes.  Instead it outputs a line like 'Program has started' and the command prompt remains open.

It takes about an hour for it to run.  After it runs, I want it to start the second command.

I've only found ways to execute commands one after the other, at the same time or with a wait condition.  I'd like to execute the first command, wait until the line 'Program has started' has been output to the screen and then I would like to run the second command.

Is there any way to do this?

```
call command1
call command2
call command3
call command4

'''Wait for a line to be output to the console, takes about an hour, line is 'Program has started'
call command2.cmd (in a new console window)
```

I currently have it set to call command 1 and then command 2, however command 2 never gets called because command 1 never closes.

Comment: `Call` is not used for 'commands', unless the 'command' is specifically another batch file.

Comment: Sorry, the commands are another batch file.  I will try the code below and will report back

Answer (score 0):

```js
@echo off
title 
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
if "%~1" == ":test" goto :test
if "%~1" == ":sender" goto :sender1
if "%~1" == ":receiver" goto :receiver
"%~f0" :sender | "%~f0" :receiver
exit /b
set quit=0
:sender1
call command1 :: waits for first 3 programs
call command2
call command3 
start /b command4 :: The program that doesn't end
:sender
if %quit% equ 1 exit
set "str="
set /p "str=>" >&2
echo(!str!
if !str! neq QUIT&&!quit! neq 1 goto :sender  
cls
exit /b
:receiver
set "LINE="
set /p "LINE="
echo !LINE!
if "!LINE!" equ "Program has started" start /b "" %0 :test    :: EDIT KEYWORD HERE
if !LINE! neq QUIT goto :receiver
set quit=1
:test
endlocal
start command5   :: triggered after command 4 prints "Program has started"
exit
```

Comment: Please do not just submit code with no supporting body text.

Comment: This did not work because I forgot to mention that I have other command files executed before hand that do close.  The first command file executed and it exited out of the my command file. I edited the original question to include a more accurate description.  The code exits with '1 was unexpected at this time' ...This is after command3.cmd gets finishes sucessfully

Comment: Working example: https://fastupload.io/ebtzcs5pAiVPaA8/file

Comment: Do command3 and 4 close or are they like command1?

Comment: Current version only waits for command1 to print keyword and then runs command2(and keeps command1 in background)

Comment: "1 was unexpected at this time" is supposed to happen btw

Comment: I think you missed my comment. How do I get it so it runs like 3 other commands first and then run the 4th command which never ends and triggers the 5 command after I hit a certain line.  I tried setting up the last two commands in another batch file but its been running far to long now and it just prints out '1 was unexpected at this time' over and over.

Comment: edited the code to include first 3 commands

Comment: if it runs too long it may be because command 4 never prints "Program has started"